# Oracle sessions stay open after closing connection

Tags: oracle, c#-2.0

While testing a new application, we came across an issue that sometimes a stored proc takes over 1 minute to execute and causes a time out. It was not 1 stored proc in particulary, it could be any.

Trying to reproduce the issue I've created a small (local) testapp that calls the same stored proc in different threads (code below).

Now it seems that the Oracle-sessions are still there. Inactive. And the CPU of the Oracle-server hits 100%.
I use the `System.Data.OracleClient`

I'm not sure if one is related to the other, but it slows down the time needed to get an answer from the database.

```
for (int index = 0; index < 1000; ++index)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(GetStreet, index);
    _runningThreads++;
    WriteThreadnumber(_runningThreads);
}

private void GetStreet(object nr)
{
    const string procName = "SPCK_ISU.GETPREMISESBYSTREET";
    DataTable dataTable = null;
    var connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CupolaDB"].ToString();
    try
    {
        using (var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new OracleCommand(procName, connection))
            {
                //Fill parameters
                using (var oracleDataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    //Fill datatable
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (dataTable != null)
            dataTable.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I just let the dba make a count of the open sessions and there are 105 sessions that stay open-inactive. After closing my application, the sessions are removed.

Comment: I'm sorry but... where you're closing the connection actually?

Comment: The fact that the session stays open after closing the connection is very likely due to the fact that you have connection pooling enabled, which is the default. Does the timeout happen after a fixed amount of time or does that vary?

Comment: It's done by the using-block. This closes and disposes the connection.

Comment: @m0skit0: Using the "using" struct will close the connection.

Comment: @m0skit0: the OracleConnection is in a `using` block, which closes it.

Comment: @Mike: it varies. There's no fixed timing. About the pooling: Microsoft MSDN states that this is managed by their provider (To deploy high-performance applications, you often need to use connection pooling. However, when you use the .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle, you do not need to enable connection pooling because the provider manages this automatically.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved.

We hired an Oracle-expert to take a look at this and the problem was caused due to some underlying stored procedures that took a while to execute and consumed a lot of CPU.

After the necessary tuning, everything runs smoothly.